# Word order: "Why don't you ask him to come with your family on a camping trip."

Tags: word-order, syntax

I've just come across the following sentence in an ESL textbook:

> Why don't you ask him to come with your family on a camping trip.

I've got the feeling that this is syntactically incorrect and that the sentence should read:

> Why don't you ask him to come [on a camping trip] [with your family].

I would appreciate it if somebody could tell me

- *if* this is, in fact, wrong
- if so, why, and
- how you would analyse the syntactical parts of this sentence after the verb/predicate ([on a camping trip] = direct object / prepositional complement, [with your family] = ?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why don't you ask him to come with your family on a camping trip?

There is no direct object to *come* in this sentence; *come* is an intransitive verb, meaning it takes no object. Both of the constituents which follow *come* are preposition phrases (PP): PP follow no set order (and may stack indefinitely), so both the original sentence and your rewrite are acceptable.

Ordinarily *come* is followed by at least one locative phrase, either a full PP or an intransitive preposition or a term like *away* or *home*<sup>†</sup> which can play the same role as a preposition phrase. This expresses the source, path or goal of the motion; it may be regarded as an 'obligatory' complement, though it may be omitted if its sense is recoverable from context.

> **A:** I'm going down to the bar for a beer.
>   **B:** I'll come ∅, too.

In your sentence *on a camping trip* fills this complementary role.

The other preposition phrase, *with your family* is not obligatory. In the original sentence it must be understood as an adjunct modifying the VP headed by *come*, but when it's moved to the right of *on a camping trip* it becomes ambiguous: it may be understood to modify either the VP or *a camping trip*.

<sup>†</sup> <sub>*CGEL* in fact regards *home* as an intransitive preposition; I think this is stretching a point, and *home* should rather be regarded as a 'fused-head' PP, in which the head preposition has fused into its object.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

I don't find anything wrong with it. I would find it slightly more natural the other way round "come on a camping trip with your family", but it is not problematical as given.

The fact that the phrases can be reordered like this suggests that "on a camping trip" is not an argument of the predicate "come", but an adjunct, the same as "with your family".

Comment: +1, but I'd argue that *on a camping trip* is a locative complement, which is about 90% of the way to being obligatory with verbs of motion.